# Storing companies' working hours in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have table with millions of companies data (`name`, `address`, `phones` etc) in my Postgres database. I want to store working hours (example: `mon-fri: 9:00-12:00, 13:00-18:00; sat: 9:00-13:00`). How can I store it to be able to find all companies opened in requested time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the opening hours per weekday/per company. For storing the actual hours, a [timerange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) seems suitable.

```
create table opening_hours
(
  company_id int not null references company,
  day_of_week int not null, -- 1 = Monday
  hours timerange not null
);
```

I would use 1 for Monday because that's the ISO definition and most of Postgres' date functions work like that, so you don't need to do conversion from and to a different base number for Monday.

If there is a noon break, it would mean that the `day_of_week` gets two entries, e.g.

```
insert into opening_hours (company_id, day_of_week, hours)
values
(1, 1, timerange('09:00', '12:00')),
(1, 1, timerange('13:00', '18:00'));
```

To find the companies that are opened at a specific day and time you can use something like this:

```
select *
from company c
where exists (select *
              from opening_hours oh
              where oh.company_id = c.id
                and oh.hours @> time '17:35'
                and oh.day_of_week = 2)
```

An [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) can be used to avoid overlapping opening hours for the same day and company.